# Grails date type

Tags: date, grails, types

In my view I have something like this:

```
Date: ${it.date}
```

which has the following output:

```
Date: 2011-05-24 00:00:00.0.
```

How can I change the Date formation so that the last part(00:00:00.0) does not appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can format a date with the related tag, which is , like this:

```
<g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd" date="${it.date}"/>
```

Here more info: http://www.grails.org/GSP+Tag+-+formatDate
Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a lot of date manipulations, I'd highly suggest getting the JodaTime plugin http://www.grails.org/plugin/joda-time. It has its own tag library, and formatting the DateTime can be simply done using the toString() method.

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime()
    println (dt.toString("YYYY-MM-dd"))
```

In your case you could do the following (if using JodaTime):

```
    Date: ${it.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```